# Dynamic initialization of Traits Range object

Tags: python, range, enthought, traitsui

I'm having trouble trying to dynamically initialize a Traits **Range** object.

The following code is a very simple example of what I'm trying to do, but sadly fails with the following type error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'code'

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Int, Range
from traitsui.api import View, Item

class DynamicRange(HasTraits):
    """Dynamic initialisation of a Range object"""
    N = Int()
    R = Range(low=0, high='N')

    traits_view = View(Item('R'), Item('N'))

    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N         # initial parameter value for N

    def _N_default(self):
        return self.N

Robject = DynamicRange(N=10)
Robject.configure_traits()
```

The code works if I replace the definition of 'R' with:  R = Range(low=0, **high=10**), but then of course I don't get the dynamic initialization of the Range's high parameter that I'm seeking.

All suggestions gratefully accepted.

*** Edit after Jonathan's response ***

Here's the simple solution to my question using Jonathan's helpful suggestion below:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Range
from traitsui.api import View, Item

class DynamicRange(HasTraits):
    """Dynamic initialisation of a Range object"""
    traits_view = View(Item('R'))

    def __init__(self, N):
        self.add_trait("R", Range(0, N))

Robject = DynamicRange(N=30)
Robject.configure_traits()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method would be to define the trait not in the usual way, but within `__init__`, thus:

```
    self.add_trait("R", Range(0, N))
```

See http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/advanced.html#per-object-trait-attributes

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing a Traits/TraitsUI bug:

- https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/issues/6
- https://github.com/enthought/traits/issues/38

A work-around is to create another Trait for the low end:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Int, Range
from traitsui.api import View, Item


class DynamicRange(HasTraits):
    """Dynamic initialisation of a Range object"""

    # Upper limit of R
    N = Int()

    # Lower limit of R (not exposed to the user)
    _zero = Int(value=0)

    R = Range(low='_zero', high='N')

    traits_view = View(Item('R'), Item('N'))


Robject = DynamicRange(N=10)
Robject.configure_traits()
```

Or use @JonathanMarch's solution. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the essence of this issue, Warren.
If you want the range to be truly dynamic (not just on initialization) then this is a much better solution - as Warren's code sample illustrates.

Comment: Yes, thanks Warren, that is indeed a better solution as it allows updating within the class code. I hadn't realised that trait objects declared at the start of the class code could be initialised with passed parameters when the object is created.

Comment: Ah, but I see that passing parameters this way only works if you don't have an __init__ function in your class code

Comment: I didn't include an `__init__()` method because it didn't seem relevant to the issue.  You can add an `__init__()` method, but be sure it includes a call to the `__init__()` method of the parent class.  That is, if you have, say,  `def __init__(self, **kw):` in the class `DynamicRange`, then include the line `super(DynamicRange, self).__init__(**kw)` in the method.

Comment: @dreme -- Warren's comment here is worth study for a deeper understanding of how to use class inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification Warren. I had seen that code with the super statement before, but hadn't really understood what it was for.